# SQL grouping does not lead to average

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to solve this practise problem on SQLite.

> Find the difference between the average rating of movies released
> before 1980 and the average rating of movies released after 1980.
> (**Make sure to calculate the average rating for each movie, then the
> average of those averages for movies before 1980 and movies after.
> Don't just calculate the overall average rating before and after 1980**.

Data is [here](https://courses.edx.org/asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YDB-SQL0001+2T2020+type@asset+block/moviedata.html):

This is what I got so far (for the first group <1980):

```
select title, avg(stars) from Movie join Rating
on Movie.mID=Rating.mID
where Year<1980
group by title
```

Can someone help with a **simple** solution? I do not know how to move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
select ((select avg(test) from (Select avg(stars) as test from Rating join Movie
on Rating.mID=Movie.mID
group by title
Having year<1980))-(select avg(test) from (Select avg(stars) as test from Rating join Movie
on Rating.mID=Movie.mID
group by title
Having year>1980)))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't aggregate by the `title`.  It is the *id* that distinguishes the movies, not the title (which could be repeated in theory).

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select m.mID, avg(case when m.year < 1980 then r.stars end) as pre_1980_avg,
       avg(case when m.year > 1980 then r.stars end) as post_1980_avg
from Movie m join
     Rating r
     on m.mID = r.mID
group by m.mID;
```

Comment: i do not get the one number from it.

Comment: @learner If you need one value (by the whole data array) then simply comment/remove GROUP BY clause and `m.mID,` in output list.

Comment: Code does not work. First I need the average of all movies  by name then before 1980 und after. Then average this two number into one number. – learner 7 mins ago   Delete

Comment: @learner . . . I'm leaving it up to you to subtract the two values.  You can add `title` to the `group by` and `select` but if you want results *per movie*, then the `id` would seem like the right granularity.

Answer (score 0):

First get the average for each movie and then use conditional aggregation on the results:

```
select 
  avg(case when m.year < 1980 then t.stars end) -
  avg(case when m.year >= 1980 then t.stars end) dif
from movie m
inner join (
  select mid, avg(stars) stars
  from rating
  group by mid
) t on t.mid = m.mid
```

If the requirement does not include the year 1980 then change `m.year >= 1980` to `m.year > 1980`.

Comment: I got the right number from this code. Is it possible to get the solution only with subqueries?

Comment: No you need a join.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without case when? I do not understand this function.

Comment: This is called conditional aggregation. A simple `avg(t.stars)` returns the average of **all** movies because **all** `t.stars` are included in the calculation. But `avg(case when m.year < 1980 then t.stars end)` includes only those `t.stars` for the movies of <1980. You should get used to CASE because it is very useful in SQL.

Comment: its a powerful function. This is not the same right? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: It is the same. But it should be called *expression* and not *statement*.

Comment: Are you a database admin or where you get your knowledege?

Comment: @learner the comment section is the place for clarifications and not for chit chat.